# What are the practical usage of Cloning

Tags: c#, java, clone

Can anyone give me a practical usage where clone is used, I understand how its done and what are the types in it, but I dont see its practical usage. Also I read it somewhere that it is used to save the state of the object, but I still think that rarely the entire state of object would be so important.

Comment: Cloning, or copying in general?  (The latter is almost always preferred.)

Comment: E.g. we want to change statement of object in method, but after this method executing we want object to get back to initial state.

Comment: I can't. I've been programming in Java since May 1997 and I've never found a use for it, or 'copy constructors' either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an object y encapsulated (for instance it is private) within object X, but you provide an accessor method (such as getY()) then you risk returning the reference to your private object and that's not good. You don't want client code to be able to get the reference to it. So instead you might copy or clone the object within getY(). As mentioned though copying is probably preferred vs. clone -- see Effective Java item 11.

Here is the example code:

```
public class X {
    private Date y = new Date();

    // other code here

    public Date getY() {
        //this could be bad:
        //return y;
        //this is good:
        return new Date(y);
    }
```

Comment: Whoops forgot to mention another reference: Effective Java item 24 has info on defensive copying.

Comment: A very logical answer, Thank you!! I will dig more on Defensive Copying

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you load your object properties to a form then bind each property to a (textbox,combobox, ...), after you do changes to the (textbox, checkbox,...) even if you cancel you can't get the original values, **so cloning is the best option**,

clone your object then bind, if you want to cancel the original object is always unchanged, this is just one case